# Windows Form after close and reopen, FindForm() is null (async await WinForms with WPF content )

Tags: wpf, winforms, async-await, winforms-interop

I have a windows usercontrol which in turn has a elementhost (to display wpf content inside the usercontrol).

```
public partial class HostControl : UserControl
{
    internal ElementHost elementHost { get; set; }
    internal System.Windows.Controls.Control Content { get; set; }

    public HostControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void HostControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.elementHost = new ElementHost();            
        this.elementHost.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;            
        this.elementHost.Child = this.Content; 
        this.Controls.Add(this.elementHost);
    }

    public void CloseWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.FindForm().Close();

    }
}
```

The HostControl.Load event  is bound to HostControl_Load event handler (above).
The closewindow eventhandler  from the hostcontrol (above) is bound to a button in the wpf view

```
            HostControl control = new HostControl();
            AView aView = new AView();             //WPF View
            control.Content = aView;
            if(aView.DataContext != null && aView.DataContext is AViewModel )
            {
                var viewModel = aView.DataContext as AViewModel;
                viewModel.CloseRequest += control.CloseWindow;
            }
```

WPF view is a usercontrol and the xaml code looks like

```
 <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:AViewModel/>
  </UserControl.DataContext>
```

A button inside this  wpf view is bound to the  OK command handler below

```
public class AViewModel
{
        public event EventHandler CloseRequest; //bound to hostcontrol's CloseWindow handler

        private async  void OK(object parameter)
        {

                await Generate();
                CloseRequest(this, EventArgs.Empty)
        }

        private async void Generate()
        {

            //Some processing here
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }

}
```

The problem I am facing is as follows.

1) As soon as the await Generate() completes, the CloseRequest triggers the CloseWindow event handler in HostControl .

2) If I do not close the wpf view, the Generate() method completes and calls the CLoseWindow handler- FindForm() has a valid parent and the view closes.

3) If I close the wpf view and re-open the view while the Generate() method is under execution, later once CloseWindow handler gets executed FindForm() is Null and a null reference exception occurs ( basically the hostcontrol's Parent is null after re-opening the form)

4) I notice that using the async and await constructs is causing an issue (?)

My question is why would the Parent of the Windows Form UserControl be set to null on re-opening the window ?

Comment: Async/await does not actually fix the infamous DoEvents() problems.  It is up to you to ensure that async code stops running when the control is disposed.  Consider using the `this.IsDisposed` property to take the sting out of this code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.The async code should not stop when the form is closed, the processing has to continue however on re-opening the wpf view the parent Form has to be initialized appropriately.

Comment: Running the same async method twice just produces more undebuggable problems, another classic DoEvents failure mode.  Clearly that code should not be associated with the UserControl at all.

Comment: Once the OK button handler is in execution mode, I disable the OK button and re-enable it only after the OK button handler returns. There by, the executions are paced and there would be no room for immediate execution of the handler until a previous invocation returned. You mean async code should never be tied to a button in a usercontrol (wpf or winforms) ?

Comment: Another note I tried using a BackgroundWorker component and got rid of async/await constructs. I that case too the FindForm() returned null on re-opening the form.